# Laravel auth on existing project

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have been working on a 'laravel' project and now want to implement an authentication. I have done 'make:auth' and the folders, routes, views etc show in the project as expected.

I have added links to login and register at the top of my homepage. When either of these links are selected they try to redirect as you would expect... So clicking login is changing URL to /login, however, I am not seeing the login page content. I get the following error message:

> Trying to get property of non-object

And it has highlighted `<?php echo e($film->title); ?>` which is on my comments page.

I don't mind if the user is able to view all the pages and content when not logged in. I am just adding auth so that I can store comments against a user.

Why is it giving me this error /  how can I fix it?

Routes:

```
/* display list of all films*/
Route::get('/', 'FilmsController@display');

/* display film comments*/
Route::get('/{id}', 'FilmsController@comment');

Route::post('/{id}', 'FilmsController@addComment')->name('addComment');
Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'FilmsController@deleteComment')->name('deleteComment');
Route::get('/update/{id}', 'FilmsController@editComment')->name('editComment');
Route::post('/update/{id}', 'FilmsController@saveComment')->name('saveComment');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Home page view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Films</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    @if (Route::has('login'))
    <div class="top-right links">
        @auth
        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
        @else
        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
        <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
        @endauth
    </div>
    @endif

    <h1>Films</h1>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Director</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Released</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($films as $film)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/{{ $film->id }}">{{$film->title}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{$film->director}}</td>
        <td>{{$film->description}}</td>
        <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($film->date)->format('l\\, jS \\of F Y\\, h:i A') }}</td>
    </tr>

@endforeach

</body>
</html>
```

Comments view

```
<h1>{{ $film->title }}</h1>
<!--<p>{{$film->comments}}</p>-->
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
@foreach ($film->comments as $comment)
    <tr>

        <td>{{$comment->body}}</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td><a href="/update/{{$comment->id}}">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="/delete/{{$comment->id}}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
<div>@include('form')</div>
```

The home controller and views remain as the were created by `make:auth`...

Home view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Home controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Film Controller function which relates to displaying comments:

```
/* Displays comments for a film*/
public function comment($id)
{
    $film = Film::find($id);
    return view('comment', compact('film'));
}
```

All my other code works apart from this. I am getting this error when I just click the login/register link. I don't see the page content at all. It takes you straight to the object error.

Comment: display part of the code

Comment: Please show routes and the view. Also, you're getting this error when you just click login or when you enter email and password and then press login?

Comment: That error indicates that `$film` is null, please provide some more relevant code.

Comment: I have added more code. If there is anything I have missed that would help please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:

```
<h1>{{ $film->title }}</h1>
```

You need to return `$film` with the `Film` object in it from the controller method that renders `comments` view. For example:

```
return view('comments', ['film' => Film::find(1)]);
```

Also, put these route at the end of the `web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'FilmsController@comment');
Route::post('/{id}', 'FilmsController@addComment')->name('addComment');
```

Comment: I have added my current code relating to what you just put above. Please can you help me understand why it is this not sufficient when it works fine until dealing with auth?

Comment: @Dan you also should put two routes at the end of the routes file to avoid errors. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Alexey. Why these two routes particularly?

Comment: @Dan because `@comment` one can be executed if you go to `/login` URI, for example. And you don't want that.

Comment: I just noticed that if I change the return view as suggested it is bringing back result 1 regardless of which page id I am on. Previously it displayed the comments related to the page id. I understand you said that I need to return the variable with the object but find(1) is not a solution I can use. Can you suggest alternative ?

Comment: @Dan `find()` method will return an object with a specified primary key. So, if you want to get object by its ID, pass it to the controller and then to `find($id)`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to look for documentation but couldn't find anything.